# filtering JSON object on an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, json

I have some data looking like:

```
var items = [
{   "id" : 1,
    "title" : "this",
    "groups" : [
        {"id" : 1,
        "name" : "groupA"},
        {"id" : 2,
        "name" : "groupB"}
    ]
},
{   "id" : 2,
    "title" : "that",
    "groups" : [
        {"id" : 1,
        "name" : "groupA"},
        {"id" : 3,
        "name" : "groupC"}
    ]
},
{   "id" : 3,
    "title" : "other",
    "groups" : [
        {"id" : 3,
        "name" : "groupC"},
        {"id" : 2,
        "name" : "groupB"}
    ]
}]
```

And I want to filter based on the group ids but I'm having trouble even accessing them - item.group returns the whole object and doing anything else (i.e. item.groups.id) returns a null or undefined value.

Any help about how to do this would be great. Essentially I want to filter the array to include all items that are in a specific group.

Thanks

Comment: Bad data structure. You should not have group info in each `item.groups` array. Groups should have a separate array or be a Map and the `item.groups` array should only have the group indexes, or a references to the group items. This will reduce the size of the JSON and make your data easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
group3Items = items.filter(item => item.groups.findIndex(group => group.id==3) > -1)
```

Comment: I noticed that soon as I had pasted the solution. Fixed :)

Comment: also checkout [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). the result becomes: `group3Items = items.filter(item => item.groups.includes(group => group.id==3))`. but note that you need a polyfill because `includes` is an es2017 feature

Comment: Thanks, Yes, which is why I opted for findIndex :).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

1. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array mapping every item in the array to a new object by
2. cloning every item using the [spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)* and override the `groups` key with a new array made from the original by using
3. [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to keep only the objects with the correct `id`.

*need a transpiler such as babel or typescript though

OR

If you wanted to flatten the structure, then you could use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to combine the arrays.

---

The code below has two outputs:

1. one keeps the original structure but filters out the items in the group that don't have an id of `3`.
2. one flattens the structure and outputs just one array.

```js
const items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "this",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "groupA"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "groupB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "that",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "groupA"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "groupC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "other",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "groupC"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "groupB"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filteredRemovingGroups = items.map(item => ({
   ...item,
   groups: item.groups.filter(subItem => subItem.id === 3)
}));

const filterAndFlatten = items.map(item =>
  item.groups.filter(subItem => subItem.id === 3)
).reduce((combinedArr, arr) => [...combinedArr, ...arr], [])

console.log('filteredRemovingGroups', filteredRemovingGroups);
console.log('filterAndFlatten', filterAndFlatten);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "this",
  "groups": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "groupA"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "groupB"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "that",
  "groups": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "groupA"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "groupC"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "other",
  "groups": [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "groupC"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "groupB"
  }]
}]

// A filter function to filter out the matched value
function filterArray(array, val) {
  return array.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.id === val; // filtering by Id
  })
}

// first filtering the original items array, & will get the object where id is 1
var obj = filterArray(items, 1);
//the previous result will return an array,
//so doing obj[0] which will give the first index. 
//obj[0].groups will be an array again

var filterGroup = filterArray(obj[0].groups,1) // will be an array which contains the matched group
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pneef57n/)